Colour scheme for this graph
How to produce a graph with the colour scheme used in the graph shared below?

I have the following code for measuring the eigenstate and eigenvalue
{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}], 
    DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 0, True]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 1, 
   Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"FEAST", "Interval" -> {3040, 3042}}, 
     "PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}}}];

DensityPlot[Evaluate[funs[[1]]^2], {x, y} \[Element] Region[Disk[]], 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, Function[{x, y}, ColorData[{"GrayYellowTones", "Reverse"}][x]], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ExclusionsStyle -> None]

The above DensityPlot with ColorFunction -> "GrayYellowTones" produces a graph as shared below

How to modify the Colour Scheme to get 2nd graph similar to the 1st graph?

Maybe Blend[colors, x] and the colors take from the pictures.
colors = 
  DominantColors[Import["https://i.sstatic.net/8I3JckTK.png"]];
DensityPlot[Evaluate[funs[[1]]^2], {x, y} ∈ Region[Disk[]], 
 ClippingStyle -> Automatic, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Blend[colors, x]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, ExclusionsStyle -> None]



Can't there be a way to manually define a colour scheme?? Like some authors use jet[u_?NumericQ] from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9321152
